# Proof of a claim on a continuous function in [0,1]

Tags: calculus, continuity

This question has given me a huge headache, and I can safely say I hate everything about it. I need to prove, that for a continuous function in [0,1],which has the property that for every x in the domain, f(x) > x, exists a d > 0 , so for every x in the domain f(x) > x + d.

I understand this is true because of the rational density theorem, but I just can't figure out how to show this. I tried using the definition of a uniformly continuous function, but that didn't go so well. I'm pretty sure i'm missing something stupid here, and i'll love a hint on how I could proceed, thank you!

Answer (score 11):

HINT: The function $g(x)=f(x)-x$ is continuous; apply the [extreme value theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem) to it.

Comment: Now I feel kind of stupid because of how easy this was, thank's a lot :)

Comment: @Xsy: You’re welcome.

Comment: Brian M. Scott, I'm just pinging you here to say your recent absence has been noticed and that I for one miss your contributions. I know we don't see eye to eye about everything, but I'd be willing to make some concessions.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I miss you also, and I wish you would return.

Comment: Brian... ${}{}{}$